# renderView fails when using Symfony2 with SwiftMail

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to use SwiftMailer in Symfony2.
To start with, I created a new controller and copied the sample from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html.
When I try to execute `renderView` I get the following error-message: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in  var/www/project/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 84`.

I tried various things, but they always will end up in an error in the controller.

Not only `renderView` but also `$this->get('mailer')->send($message);` is throwing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just instantiate a controller as a usual class and then call its methods, because you don't get the service container injected then. Create a mailer service instead. Read the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) chapter for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change the order, get `mailer` before creating new swift_message as such:

```
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
```

Comment: Sorry, but it fails too. The error is now on line 189 in Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php instead of 84.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/project/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 189 `

Comment: It seems you have nothing to do with swiftmailer. The problem is in your **new controller**; make sure it is correctly set

Comment: I've found out what my problems is or better what is causing it. I want to instantiate a new Controller when I'm accesssing the other Controller, which lives in another bundle. I don't know how to fix it or what is the proper way to do it. Any hints are very appreciated, sorry I'm not very experienced with symfony.